# Как получить значение из датафрейма?

Tags: pandas, numpy

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить определенное значение в колонке "Score"?

```
models = pd.DataFrame({
    'Model' : ['Logistic Regression', 'Decision Tree Classifier', 'GridSearchCV_clf', 'Random Forest Classifier',
             'Gradient Boosting Classifier', 'XgBoost'],
    'Score' : [lr_acc, dtc_acc, GridSearchCV_clf_acc, rd_clf_acc, gb_acc, xgb_acc]
})

models["Score"] = (models["Score"] * 100).round(2)

models.sort_values(by = 'Score', ascending = False)
```

Я попробовал вот такой вариант

```
best_model = models.sort_values(by = 'Score', ascending = False).iloc[:1]
```

но мне нужно не число, а именно

> ```
> [lr_acc, dtc_acc, GridSearchCV_clf_acc, rd_clf_acc, gb_acc, xgb_acc]
> ```

Comment: может по максимальному значению из столбца проще?

Comment: Да, по максимальному значению из столбца, но мне нужно не само значение, а переменная, на которую оно ссылается

Comment: что значит `переменная, на которую ссылается`? -  всю строку? индекс строки? или название модели, в которой у вас лучший скор?

Comment: Название модели, в которой лучший скор. Извиняюсь, если не совсем корректно изъясняю свои мысли, просто это моя первая задачка

Answer (score 1):

Видимо так:

```
models.iloc[models['Score'].idxmax()]['Model']
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавите еще один столбец `'Name'` с именами переменных:

```
models = pd.DataFrame({
    'Model' : ['Logistic Regression', 'Decision Tree Classifier', 'GridSearchCV_clf', 'Random Forest Classifier',
             'Gradient Boosting Classifier', 'XgBoost'],
    'Score' : [lr_acc, dtc_acc, GridSearchCV_clf_acc, rd_clf_acc, gb_acc, xgb_acc],
    'Name':   'lr_acc, dtc_acc, GridSearchCV_clf_acc, rd_clf_acc, gb_acc, xgb_acc'.split(", ")
})
```

Тогда после ваших команд

```
models["Score"] = (models["Score"] * 100).round(2)

models.sort_values(by = 'Score', ascending = False)
```

вы получите например

> ```
>    Model                         Score                 Name
> 4  Gradient Boosting Classifier 1100.0 gb_acc
> 1  Decision Tree Classifier     1010.0 dtc_acc
> 2  GridSearchCV_clf              723.0 GridSearchCV_clf_acc
> 0  Logistic Regression           620.0 lr_acc
> 5  XgBoost                       292.0 xgb_acc
> 3  Random Forest Classifier      184.0 rd_clf_acc
> ```

и после команды

```
best_model = models.sort_values(by = 'Score', ascending = False).iloc[:1]
```

будет `best_model` выглядеть так:

> ```
>    Model                         Score  Name
> 4  Gradient Boosting Classifier 1100.0 gb_acc
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один вариант:

```
models.max(axis=0)['Model']
```

Названия модели вам вполне достаточно, зачем вам название переменной.